# Can I move the Azure storage emulator files?

Tags: azure

Windows Azure storage emulator appears to save the data in my user profile on my C-drive. Since I have a quite small ssd and I don't really need the performance benefits when working with test data in my azure project I thought that perhaps I could move it to my D-drive.

I haven't found a way to do that, so does anybody have a suggestion on how or if I can move the storage emulator files to another drive?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following solution works, although it's not amazingly elegant:

1. Make sure storage emulator is not running, i.e. shut it down from the notifications area if necessary.
2. Move the folder in your local AppData folder to where you want it. It will be called something like `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\dftmp`.
3. Open a command prompt with administrator permissions and `cd` to the `AppData\Local` folder. For example `cd \Users\{username}\AppData\Local`.
4. Create a 'junction link' using the following command: `mklink /J dftmp X:\folder\to\where\you\moved\dftmp`
5. Restart the storage emulator and enjoy having the files on a different drive or in a different location.

Comment: It's now different with the latest SDK. Look in `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\DevelopmentStorage` for some clues.

Comment: Same procedure with the junction link - the config file which looks like it should set where the files are stored seems to have no effect.